# pygame moving a image with keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame

I'm am having some difficult with pygame. I am attempting to create a simple game but so far I can't seem to get the basic of displaying the image and moving around the screen using the keyboard. I would love to get this resolved so I can move on and add further details but until it is I am unfortunately stuck. I would greatly appreciate any feed and support

```
enter code here import math, os, pygame, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

running = True
while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        running = False

class Game(object):
 def main(self, screen):

    background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
    image = pygame.image.load("plane.png")
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.player = Player(sprites)
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key ==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                return
        sprites.update()   
        screen.fill((200,200,200))
        screen.blit(background,(0,0))
        sprites.draw(screen)       
        pygame.display.flip()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *group):
    super(Player, self). __init__(*groups)
    self.image = pygame.image.load("plane.png")
    self.rect = pygame,rect.Rect((320, 240), self.image.get.size())

def update(self):    
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.rect.x -= 10
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.rect += 10
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.rect -= 10
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.rect += 10


if __name__ == "__main__":
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set.mode((640,480))
Game().main(screen)


class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self.color,x,y,width,height):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((width.height))
    self.image.fill(pygame.colour.Colour(colour))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect. x = x
    self.rect. y = y
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of mistakes in your code. (syntax, semantics etc.)

First the reason why you don't see anything when running the program is because of the first loop (at the very top). It will keep on running till you press `Esc` or `pygame.QUIT`. Only after that loop is broken, will the rest of the program start. Get rid of it.

Next, there are quite a few syntax , indentation issues, methods and attributes that don't exist for a particular pygame classs etc. Use [diffchecker](http://www.diffchecker.com) to compare your existing code with the one I've provided [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/MjVJvTT9)